# C#: await TransformBlock.Completion hangs without response

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I've got this:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var block = new TransformBlock<int, int>(x =>
        {
            if (x == 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("transform");
            }
            return x * 2;
        });

        var outputBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(Console.WriteLine);
        block.LinkTo(outputBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        block.Post(4);
        await block.Completion;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

It runs to the line of "await" and stops, seems it hangs. I think I already specified the "LinkTo" for a consumer for the block and called "Post" to feed input. Why Completion doesn't end?

How to fix it?

Comment: You are missing a call to `block.Complete();` before you `await` the completion.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var block = new TransformBlock<int, int>(x =>
        {
            if (x == 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("transform");
            }
            return x * 2;
        });

        var outputBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(Console.WriteLine);
        block.LinkTo(outputBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        block.Post(4);
        block.Complete();
        await block.Completion;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

The extra call to Complete method on ActionBlock is required to  execute the Post operation.

You can look at the [source code here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Blocks/ActionBlock.cs#L220) too.